# How to send the mail automatically to respective user before a specific time?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I Have a system which is managing the document authorization on different hierarchy level, In this i need the system to automatically mail to the user for some reminder/notification before 3 days of expiry, I am using PHP MYSQL APACHE

How can I Achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a script, and let cron job do the automatic email sending for you

Or you can use [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)

Comment: Thats What I Need to know How would I integrate this Cron job thing with my Script?

Comment: I am not aware of cron job never created any

Comment: i think you should create a script specifically to check the database for subscription which are about to expire, then you need to run it everyday in cron..

Comment: This Is what i need how to make it run everyday automatically?

Comment: in your hosting provider, they allow you to run cron jobs. i think you can find it in the feature of your provider..

Answer (score 1):

You can really only do this with Cron. If your server is a Linux host, you can schedule a PHP script (which you'll need to write) to run at a set time, e.g. every minute. Your script will check against the users database, select any users that are 3 days from expiry and mail them. Setting up cron is host-specific and your hosting provider might not even let you do it. Usually you'll have some server administration software (e.g. cPanel) that will let you schedule a cron job and specify which script to run. If you have SSH access, even easier - you can just SSH in and run `crontab -e` to set up a cron schedule yourself. There are plenty of cron tutorials on Google.

Check with your hosting provider if they allow scheduled activities.